# Avoid Hbase error org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: Name

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Currently I'm developing an application query image using Hbase + Hadoop. Hbase will be used to store images. Then using map reduce to query image from Hbase and compare similarity with with user's input image.

I'm using Hadoop 1.21 and Hbase 0.94 (pseudo-distributed mode).

My mapper is constructed as :

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
          sourceTable,      // input table
          scan,             // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
          MyMapper.class,   // mapper class
          null,             // mapper output key
          null,             // mapper output value
          job);
```

The problem is when I run it from eclipse, I always get exception :

```
15/07/17 19:10:53 WARN client.ScannerCallable: Ignore, probably already closed
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: Name: 744820520766260875
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.close(HRegionServer.java:2758)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1434)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:995)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.close(ScannerCallable.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ServerCallable.withRetries(ServerCallable.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableRecordReaderImpl.nextKeyValue(TableRecordReaderImpl.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableRecordReader.nextKeyValue(TableRecordReader.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
```

And even the map reduce function still run 100%.

So my question is why I got this error. 
How to fix it?

Anyone can help me?

Thanks